# How are the constituent quark masses determined?

Tags: quarks, confinement

I was wondering how the constituent quark masses are determined (in wikipedia they claim $m_{u/d,const}\approx 350 $ MeV), but how is this in practise determined or estimated? I could not find any source for it, just that it differs by the "model" used, whatever that means in this context.

Comment: What does u/d, const mean?

Comment: Which Wikipedia page?

Comment: Maybe [the R(s) ratio](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2012/hadronic-xsections/rpp2012-sigma_R_ee_plots.pdf) defined as $R(s)\equiv\frac{\sigma(e^+e^- \rightarrow \text{Hadrons})}{\sigma(e^+e^- \rightarrow \mu^+ \mu^-)}$ can help you. Each "step" (hard to see, though) corresponds to a parameter $\sqrt{s}$, the center-of-mass energy (if I'm not mistaken), while we have $R(s)\approx 3\sum_{q\lesssim\sqrt{s}} Q_q^2$. Here, $q$ is a quark, and $Q_q$ is its electric charge.

Comment: @JEB const is short for "constituent", u/d means that this applies to the up or down quark (constituent mass for other quarks is heavier)

Comment: with u/d,const I mean the constituent mass of the $u$ and $d$ quark which are about the same. The wiki page is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_quark which only refers to the Griffith's but I don't have access to this book rn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constituent_quark) suggests, they are  "effective", long-distance, nonperturbative masses in additive quark models of the 60s and early 70s. They were fit from hadron masses assuming additivity. Subsequently, with the advent of the QCD lagrangian, current "undressed", short-distance quarks in QCD and perturbation theory replaced them.

In their heyday, constituent quarks were sort of like nuclear physics constituents. They were chunks with a big mass, above the QCD scale, about 340MeV, simply *added together*  to produce masses of hadrons, baryons and non-pseudoscalar mesons. So, e.g., the masses of the proton and neutron were the masses of two such ups and a down; and two such downs and an up, respectively. The mass of a $\rho ^+$, the mass of an up such, and and anti down (equal to the mass of the down),  and so forth.

All kinds of models were devised about the binding of such, oscillator models, etc..

The Gell-Mann-Okubo style formulas, the prediction of the *Ω* mass, etc, were early triumphs of the eightfold way, for which they served as a shortcut of the math of SU(3) breaking. The hadron magnetic moments were, actually, [predicted nicely by such a constituent quark model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleon_magnetic_moment#Quark_model_of_nucleon_magnetic_moments)!

Their terrible weakness were the pseudoscalar mesons. If the positive pion were $u\bar d$, why would its mass be almost 1/5 of their summed mass? After unravelling of the chiral symmetry breaking effected by QCD, it was understood that pseudo scalars, the pseudogoldstone bosons of chiral symmetry breaking, were, in fact, controlled/shaped by *current* quark masses (GOR), instead, and constituent quarks had *nothing* to do with them.

So, what are they? where do they live? How are their early baryon magnetic moment triumphs to be explained in nonperturbative QCD? How  is the bloating from the current mass of each, $m_{cur}\to m_{const}$,  to be explained?
$$
u~~~~~~2\to 336\\
d ~~~~~4.5 \to 340\\
s~~~~100\to 486\\
c~1300\to 1550\\ ...
$$

The most successful models are the [chiral bag](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0370-1573(96)00013-0), cloudy bag models, relying on the likely fact that chiral symmetry breaking occurs slightly *within* the confinement radius, so there is a shell between
chiral condensation and confinement radii, where quarks are not almost massless current ones anymore, but have bloated (mass-wise) to hadron constituents, an effective theory requiring some type of goldstones-pseudoscalars (see above) as independent, effective degrees of freedom, to boot! (A counterintuitive σ model of sorts. A vision.) The fantasy of WP linked as them being some type of marshmallow with a current quark kernel and a fuzz of gluons and quark-antiquark pairs might be what unscrupulous popular science reporters might picture. It's a long, dark, mysterious story...

Modern researchers often rely on well-founded lattice QCD simulations for the nonperturbative answers, and unjustly ignore constituent quarks.